# Specific Lebesgue integration question

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm stuck on the follow practice problem, can anyone help:

Prove that:
$\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{0}^{R} \cos{x} /(1+x) dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin{x} /(1+x)^2$ dx

Comment: Integrate by parts.

Comment: As it's a high level course I thought i mignt require something more interesting and didn't even think to try that. I'll give it a go, cheers

Comment: It works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried justifying integration by parts?

Comment: your right int by parts works fine if I just split up the integral into an infinite sum